# Why enabling addons on EKS is so slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, csi-driver

Enabling aws-ebs-csi-driver via terraform takes 15 minutes each time. It slows down our pipeline and even caused few problems with some tokens being expired.

I could not find any documentation about how exactly EKS addons works.
Effectively what I end up with are few extra pods in my cluster.
I could do the same with fluxcd and it would be faster (just download time of images which I believe would take under 1 minute).

I used EKS addons as a first try (I know it's a relatively new thing) and my expectation was that it will make my life easier.

I found no references to any plugin name in EKS terraform module that I use. That makes me thing that under the hood EKS addons is a separate set of microservices and that deployment of plugins is asynchronous (that's for sure), maybe queued and for whatever reason it takes surprisingly long (which makes our tests to take much longer, increases cloud costs etc)

1. Did anyone try to deploy aws-ebs-csi-driver yourself vs using addon and could share his experience?
2. Maybe some Aws developers could share some details how these addons installations are implemented?

Comment: I ended up installing aws-ebs-csi-driver via flux and as expected it makes whole process faster by 15 minutes. I think the most popular case for EKS Addon is usage of gp3. FYI: together with flux deployment you need to disable gp2 as a default storage class via terraform.